# Getting the source code of web pages in the same network

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, xmlhttprequest

The tool that I'm developing takes as parameter a url and retrieves the source code from that url to analyze. The tool will be hosted in our domain, and it should have the ability to analyze web pages of sites that are in the same internal network domain. I make this Jquery.ajax call to retrieve the source code :

```
$.ajax({
    url: siteToanalyze,
    type : 'GET',
    dataType : 'html',
    success: function (result) {
        content = result;
    analyzeCode(content, siteToanalyze);
    },
    error: function (jqxhr, status, errorThrown) {
    alert("Failure, Unable to recieve content");
    }
 });
```

I can get the code using YQL for external web sites as well. I can get source code for web pages from the same origin. But what about web pages in the same internal network, that are not accessible to YQL.

For instance, if this js code is served from 172.20.1.160:5000 and we give a site in 172.20.5.68:5000 in the same network. The web console shows a HTTP 200 status request for the url, but results in the error function being run. Why does that happen? Or is there some other way to get source code of web pages other than the way I mentioned?

Comment: try setting dataType to text.And what is the error thrown

Comment: your code has a lot syntax errors, try using text-editors with syntax-highlighting.

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui sorry, this is not the original code, I've deleted some parts when making the question here. That's why there were syntax errors.

Comment: @iBlue Then still the error is thrown, but the status is 'parseerror'

Comment: @phabtar what is siteToanalyze?

Comment: it's the url of the page I want analyzed : in this instance say  "http://172.20.5.68:5000/ALSI"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was indeed because of the [Same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript). The content I wanted to access is from a different origin than that of the above code. I solved the issues using [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)